# Can't test my Java Webservice on Weblogic

Tags: java, web-services, testing, weblogic, webservice-client

I am following these steps: [steps](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A75z0_QvWfc)

But when I try to run it on the server, I get this: [image: error]

Could anyone help me, how could I test my webservice? Thank you!

Comment: Copy paste your error stack trace here. Don't post an image of that. Its not at all readable.

Comment: but there is no error stack trace! you can see the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to connect to the root directory- normally you would be pointing at a file such as a wsdl, or the web services link in weblogic.
Try connecting outside of eclipse - use a browser. Navigate to the server console (hostname:port/console in weblogic development mode), then try going to the webservice from within there. There is a link to the test point.

Answer (score 0):

Don't "Run" the Project, Run the Class (TestWS.java).
This will bring you the Service Test Point in Eclipse.
The other way it's the described by FlareStar.